# php check if img src is image

Tags: php, image, src

I have this code, which should display image if it gets one generated, or write "no image" if not.

```
<body>
    <?php
        $src = "somescript.php";
    //  if (getimagesize($src)) {
        if (file_exists($src)) {
            echo '<img src="'.$src.'" />';
        } else {
            echo "no image";
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

`somescript.php` is local file which generates image, or `die();`

The problems are:
`file_exists` condition always doesn't return anything.
`getimagesize` condition always return "failed to open stream".

Anyone have an idea how to get it work?

Comment: For one, I wouldn't bother checking the image size until you've checked that it exists.

Comment: is somescript.php in the same directory as this file? You're not giving it a full path, so it's not going to find it otherwise.

Comment: You'r given the wrong path.

Comment: use client-side code, f.e. with jQuery, to get the image or present "no image" to the user. Otherwise `somescript.php` will have to generate the same image twice...

Comment: Without knowing what somescript.php does, I would recommend returning a status code indicating that the image was found/created.  Then you could just check for the status code to determine success/failure.

Just a note, if somescript.php exists, your test will **always** pass.  You're checking whether or not somescript.php exists, not whether an image exists.

Comment: I think you can run each file through gd to determine if they are images.
and @WouterHuysentruit , Client-side code may be a good ui tweak, but you can easily disable javascript, or even write your own forms... so no good. If you don't care about malicious users however... go ahead :)

Comment: @Mike Yes, somescript.php is in the same directory as this file.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I'd like to avoid JS as the image is generated on server and on server it should be (not) displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems appropriate to only generate the image once for each request, I would handle this at client side.

You can get the image using jQuery on document load and decide whether to show the image or show "no image".

Or you can keep the `img` tag, but use javascript to detect errors in the image:

**CSS**

```
#mynoimg { display: none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="myimg" src="somescript.php" />
<div id="mynoimg">no image</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("myimg").onerror = function() {
    this.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("mynoimg").style.display = "block";
}
```

or using jQuery:

```
$("#myimg").error(function () { // when image doesn't load correctly
    $(this).hide();             // hide it
    $("#mynoimg").show();       // and show "no image" message instead
});
```

Comment: Even if javascript is what I wanted to avoid, I didn't have other choice, but to accept this answer, because it is the only one working. Thank you @Wouter.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're passing a full-blown URL to `filexists()`, it's going to be working on a local filesystem path, which may NOT have any relationship whatsoever to the url of the image you're passing in to the `<img>` tag. e.g.

- your script is /home/sites/example.com/html/foo/picture.php
- your images live in /home/sites/example.com/html/images/...
- you're trying to pass in /images/foo.jpg to the  tag

Then the following url -> path lookups will take place:

you pass `file_exists('/images/foo.jpg')`: PHP will check for the local system path `/images/foo.jpg`. You're not serving your site out of the server's root directory, so this fails.

you try `file_exists('images/foo.jpg')`: PHP will check `/home/site/example.com/html/foo/images/foo.jpg` - a subdirectory of the dir your script is running from. Also doesn't exists, and you get false.

You cannot generally mix filesystem-space and URL-space paths like you seem to be. The two spaces are related, but not directly connected.

Comment: I believe this is not my case. The somescript.php is not returning path, but whole image instead. And while somescript.php is in the same directory as the page I'm calling it from, the src="somescript.php" is representing that file in local directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of file_exists

```
$src = 'somescript.php';
$src_headers = @get_headers($src);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

Comment: Works great. You only need to change the condition, as in different cases the error can be 404, 403, etc. Worked great for me in Facebook Graph API with forbidden images.